# How to realize the GPS cold start, warm start , hot start?

Tags: android, gps

How to realize the GPS cold start, warm start , hot start ?
Does anyone have any idea about it? Thanks for any help !

Comment: What do you mean by "realize"?  Can you try re-wording your question?

Comment: I think the OP means "determine"

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique described in about 5 minutes starting at 49:43 of [this 2010 Google I/O session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/beginners-guide-android.html) that starts multiple location listeners and then "backs off" the less accurate but immediately available listeners as the more accurate but more delayed listeners become available.